# Adjustable input field Internet Explorer cakephp

Tags: internet-explorer, cakephp

I have an input field that might require a lot of text. On a mac I can adjust the field to whatever size I want, see first image, but on a pc(Internet Explorer) I get the scrolly bar of doom, see other image. Is there a way to duplicate that? Or am I stuck setting it to a certain height(Can I do that?)?

Image 1:

[image: The little arrow on the bottom right of the image let's me adjust it.]

Image 2:

[image: Scrolling bar of doom on the bottom right, annoying with lots of text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does not provide resizability for textareas as do other browsers (as of some time ago).

You can find javascript online that adds the functionality, but in my opinion it is more cumbersome than useful as it has to add a div and movement hooks to resize the field when the div is moved etc.

Comment: Thank you, we'll just have them use chrome, only a few users will be accessing it anyways.